# Django authentication failing with a 403 with no detailed message

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have something pretty simple which I've thrown together. I have a little form like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" action>
    <input name="email_address" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <a id="loginButton">Login</a>
</form>
```

My JavaScript does the following:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(){
    $.post("/login/",$("#loginForm").serialize(), function(data) {
        console.log("login.");
    });
});
```

I've written a custom Django authentication backend:

```
from my.custom.project.models import User

class MyBackend:

    def authenticate(self, email_address=None, password=None):
        print "Trying to auth"
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email_address=email_address, password=password)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I have this configured in my `settings.py` like so:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "my.custom.project.auth.MyBackend",
)
```

In my actual view for the `/login/` path, here's what I have:

```
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request):
    print "Trying to auth..."
    email_address = request.POST['email_address']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(email_address=email_address, password=password)

    if user != None:
        auth.login(request, user)

    direct_to_template(request, "my/login/template.json")
```

Here's my URL map:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^admin/doc', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('my.project.views',
    (r'^$', 'root'),
    (r'^login/?$', 'login'),
    (r'^logout/?$', 'logout'),
)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? All I get in the Django server output is:

```
[16/Sep/2011 20:17:47] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2326
```

Am I taking crazy pills? What did I overlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all because of Django's built-in CSRF system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you do is

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
```

and then redefine login

```
def login(request):
```

and then call the other one again, which is not reachable anymore (overwritten by your own login function).

```
login(request, user)
```

Not sure though if that’s causing the error though.

Comment: :( Nope, still the same issue. I'll update my question to include that fix.

Comment: What's weird is that I'm not hitting any of the log statements I have in there, I'm getting nothing.

Comment: So how did you register the /login/ view?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the problem is with the URL mapping, as it's working just fine for other elements, and 403 is for something that is forbidden, like there's some kind of permission set on it blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the line:

```
return User.objects.get(email_address=email_address, password=password)
```

implies that the User record stores the password as-is, in plaintext. Whereas, in fact, it stores a salted hash of the password, so you might need to implement all that functionality yourself.

Comment: This is my own custom class, that was written just to simplify things. I am indeed salting my passwords manually, but I omitted that as I don't think it's a part of the problem here.